# Exception Handling in C# for ASP.NET FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am trying to do some error handling in item inserting for my formview. If anyone forgets to enter a value in tutorial section, the error message will detect it is null and give a popup of it being null. however, my visual studio does not recognize Exception or ExceptionHandled. The error is that there is no definition for Exception. I have searched high and low and I don't know what the problem is. Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Exception != Null)
    {
        string msg = "";
        if (e.Exception.Message.Containts("NULL"))
        {
            msg = "Tutorial Section cannot be empty.";
        }
        else
            msg = "unknown";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "window.setTimeout(\"alert('" + msg + "')\",0);", true);
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are saying I guess means validation rather error handling.

Comment: that's not it. I just want to know how come the e.Exception is not recognized.

Comment: @NegarNegaru it simply doesn't exists. [FormViewInsertEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewinserteventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I see. I assumed since it exists in listview it should exist in formview as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protected void FormView1_ItemInserting` event has no `Exception`

You have to use `Inserted` event handler, not `Inserting` event!

Like this:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Error : " + e.Exception.Message;

        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
     else
     {
        Label1.Text = "Inserted Successfully";
     }
}
```